# Unity2D disable player collision with ennemy when taking damage

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

My player has multiple hearts, and i want to damage him one heart for every collision with an ennemy, but after each collision i want him to be invulnerable for a certain amout of time, and making him able to pass through the ennemy, thought about disabling his BoxCollider2D for a moment but that makes him fall through the ground as i'm using a Rigibody2D, how can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to do this:

1-https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html

2-https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html (You will change layers for a short period of time)